# How can a spike in Mana content lead to inconsistent birth rates?

Tags: magic, moons

The moon is a celestial object that rotates around the earth and is made up of warpstone, a solidified form of mana. This warpstone radiates its energy toward earth, bathing the planet with waves of mana. This forms the basis of mana content within the environment, which is used by witches to conduct magical spells and rituals. The mana content ebbs and flows throughout the year, which is controlled by the amount of energy that the moon puts out at any given time. For this reason, the moon maintains special significance in soceity and culture, and it is worshipped by witches as the goddess known as Selune. This steady balance is disrupted by a special event known as a solar eclipse, in which the Sun, Moon, and Earth are in perfect alignment with each other. This eclipse occurs every seven years, and covers the entirety of the planet. The energy from the sun radiates the warpstone on the moon, increasing its output to the planet and causes the mana content on the planet to spike.

This uptake can be felt by all witches, who can detect the change in output leading to the actual event. The eclipse increases the magic of spells by witches that can be performed, allowing for the use of powerful and ancient rituals that are rarely used. However, this also has other adverse effects for witches who are expecting.  An impending solar eclipse has the effect of pushing labor to either side of it, inducing mothers early weeks or even months in advance or delaying it for the same amount of time. The random side effects occur for all pregnancies, and leads to premature or delayed births which can be detrimental to the resulting child.

How can this be explained?

Comment: A full moon every 500 years? it would be more distant than Pluto is from the Sun

Comment: You are looking for a magical explanation of a magical effect, correct?

Comment: If you have a magic world and want us to come up with a plausible explanation (in terms of magic) you need to tell us what the basic rules about how magic works in your world, otherwise we're just all working at cross-purposes.  Note 500 years is a long time for a society to "remember" the truth about what happened once 500 years ago and keeping written records that long is difficult without some pretty extreme distortions creeping in.

Comment: If the Moon is completely sun lit then by definition you do not have a lunar eclipse. A lunar eclipse happens when the Moon is not lit at all, because it is in Earth's shadow. (And the numbers do not work at all. You may want to check them.)

Comment: For interest: [Pern, Red Star](https://pern.fandom.com/wiki/The_Red_Star).

Answer (score 1):

#### Celestial Balance

The Sun gives power to magic while the Moon regulates that power into something safe for the world to handle on a regular basis.  Under normal circumstances, a balance is maintained and things are good.  When the eclipse happens, the moon is unlit by the sun for a short time, throwing the balance of things off for a short time.

In this case, the sun supercharges Earth's mana without the calming influence of the moon to quell things.  During these enhanced times, the more powerful magic enables greater feats of magic than would normally be possible, though could have the side effects of being unbalanced.  It is at these times that it is thought that the greatest miracles could be brought down.

But for an up, there is a down.  Very new things to the world do not fare well when brought into the world at such an unbalanced time.  Pick your reasons for that that fit with your world.  This goes doubly so for any being that is supernaturally inclined.

If the eclipses happens at a semi-regular interval, then animals will adjust to this, adapting through the ages to this magical quirk of nature.  For us more sentient folk that reproduce when we feel like it, that causes problems.  The semi-aware forces of magic have to actively prevent a child from entering the world at this unbalanced time for their own safety magically.  Unfortunately, this generally puts the child at odds with their physical development.

#### Side Effects

There will be, of course, side effects.  There will be a weeks to months long gap of no children being born with an influx of children at the edges of this period of no babies.  This could be more of a social issue than a biologic one, but it will create an inconsistent birth rate over short periods of time.

If the eclipse is world wide, then this is a global problem.  Otherwise, there will be a swath of land affected and the cure will be to travel away from the path of the eclipse which may or may not be possible.

Another side effect is that if I have it right, a lunar eclipse means that you can have a solar eclipse as well.  That might have different, and potentially opposite effects.

Comment: what effect would an inconsistent birth rate have?